# How to Check Password validation dynamically using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side-validation

**Kindly read my question fully before assign  my one as duplicate.**
Hi I tried to verify password dynamically during keypress. Actually it is working for me while enter the password. But When I delete the password only 2 conditions satisfies. My code and images below:

My password box html code is

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
 <input class="form-control" id="NewPassword" placeholder="New Password"  onkeypress="EnterPassword()" onkeydown="DeletePassword()" type="password">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
 </div>
```

I used glyphicon-remove infront of each conditions for the password. When I enter the password each icon change to glyphicon-ok if the condition satisfies.

These are my password conditions with icon:
   [image]

Lets assume my password as Password@123, it contains all my required things, so all the icons changed to ok. 
[image]

But when I delete the password only 2 of the conditions satisfied. 
[image]

Codes for the function below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
           function EnterPassword() {
            $("#NewPassword").keyup(function () {
            var regex1 = new Array();
            var regex2 = new Array();
            var regex3 = new Array();
            var regex4 = new Array();
                regex1.push("[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
                regex2.push("[a-z]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
                regex3.push("[0-9]"); //Digit.
                regex4.push("[!@@#$%^&*]"); //Special Character.
     if ($(this).val().length>6) {
      $("#Length").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < regex1.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp(regex1[i]).test($(this).val())) {
     $("#UpperCase").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
     }
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < regex2.length; i++) {
     if (new RegExp(regex2[i]).test($(this).val())) {
      $("#LowerCase").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
     }
     }
    for (var i = 0; i < regex3.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp(regex3[i]).test($(this).val())) {
     $("#Numbers").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
     }
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < regex4.length; i++) {
     if (new RegExp(regex4[i]).test($(this).val())) {
     $("#Symbols").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
     }
      }
     });
     }

function DeletePassword() {
 $("#NewPassword").keyup(function () {
var regex1 = new Array();
var regex2 = new Array();
 var regex3 = new Array();
 var regex4 = new Array();
                regex1.push("[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
                regex2.push("[a-z]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
                regex3.push("[0-9]"); //Digit.
                regex4.push("[!@@#$%^&*]"); //Special Character.
     var thisVal =$(this).val();

  if ($(this).val().length<6) {
 $("#Length").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
   }

for (var i = 0; i < regex1.length; i++) {
 if (new RegExp(regex1[i]).test(!thisVal)) {
  $("#UpperCase").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
   }
    }
 for (var i = 0; i < regex2.length; i++) {
  if (new RegExp(regex2[i]).test(!thisVal)) {
  $("#LowerCase").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
   }
  }
for (var i = 0; i < regex3.length; i++) {
  if (new RegExp(regex3[i]).test(!thisVal)) {
 $("#Numbers").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
    }
 }
  for (var i = 0; i < regex4.length; i++) {
 if (new RegExp(regex4[i]).test(!thisVal)) {
   $("#Symbols").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
    }
 }
  });
  }
    </script>
```

NOTE: UpperCase,LowerCase,Numbers,Symbols are the Id name that I gave to the  tag where I used the glyphicon remove icon.
**If my codes not working completely means my question may comes under duplicate. But Its Partially working, So kindly let me know if there is any mistake I did on my code.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: on you `onkeydown` of the input you have already defined the function `DeletePassword()` then why are you again calling the `keyup` inside the function it will be called on the `keydown` event no need to call the `keyup` inside or is there any special need for it. And the same goes for `EnetrPassword()`.

Comment: You are involving `keyup` event in the `keydown` event. I don't see the usability of the `array`s and `loop` s. Simple `if` statements will do the job. Try to avoid `inline event handlers` as much as possible.

Comment: @ths,@vikscool  :So far from your comments I understand that `keydown` and `keypress` event was assigned to a functions in the html code, then no need to use the `keyup` inside the functions, but once I removed the `keyup` functions within the delete and enter functions, the thing is not working(even for enter password).

Comment: do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: I dont have any errors so far.. while running my above code, entering password working properly.. while delete password, I want the icon to change back from right to wrong, but 2 of 5 conditions  only satisfies and icons changed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can simplify your code a lot.

For a start instead of using inline event handlers we will use jQuery's `.on` to bind the event.

Next we'll consolidate your rules into a JSON object array with the rules target.

We then iterate the Regex based rules adding and removing classes as required

```js
/*Actual validation function*/
function ValidatePassword() {
  /*Array of rules and the information target*/
  var rules = [{
      Pattern: "[A-Z]",
      Target: "UpperCase"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[a-z]",
      Target: "LowerCase"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[0-9]",
      Target: "Numbers"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[!@@#$%^&*]",
      Target: "Symbols"
    }
  ];

  //Just grab the password once
  var password = $(this).val();

  /*Length Check, add and remove class could be chained*/
  /*I've left them seperate here so you can see what is going on */
  /*Note the Ternary operators ? : to select the classes*/
  $("#Length").removeClass(password.length > 6 ? "glyphicon-remove" : "glyphicon-ok");
  $("#Length").addClass(password.length > 6 ? "glyphicon-ok" : "glyphicon-remove");
  
  /*Iterate our remaining rules. The logic is the same as for Length*/
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {

    $("#" + rules[i].Target).removeClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ? "glyphicon-remove" : "glyphicon-ok"); 
    $("#" + rules[i].Target).addClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ? "glyphicon-ok" : "glyphicon-remove");
      }
    }

    /*Bind our event to key up for the field. It doesn't matter if it's delete or not*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#NewPassword").on('keyup', ValidatePassword)
    });
```

```css
.glyphicon-remove {
  color: red;
}

.glyphicon-ok {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input class="form-control" id="NewPassword" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div id="Length" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must be at least 7 charcters</div>
<div id="UpperCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 upper case character</div>
<div id="LowerCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 lower case character</div>
<div id="Numbers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 numeric character</div>
<div id="Symbols" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 special character</div>
```

Comment: Woww.. your one work like awesome.. Thank you so much..  I already have the CSS and html codes rdy.. Now I used ur functions.. I will go through target, pattern soon.. what is the main use of this target pattern ?

Comment: The Target is the `div` that will be updated, Pattern is the `regex` pattern that is used to see if the password meets that complexity rule.  `rules` is just an array of these objects. [Here is a quick bit of info on objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Comment: I used your one and its working for me. At the same time, I wanna know what I did wrong in my code.? Do you find any mistakes in my code...Coz Its partially working right so I am asking

Comment: I didn't go through it in depth. One thing that stood out is `.test(!thisVal)` . This doesn't work. What you want instead is `if (!(new RegExp(regex4[i]).test(thisVal)))`. You need to negate the result of the test, not the value being tested.

Comment: Thank you so much once again.. Its working if I change my code as per ur above comment.. But I put that one as alternative one and I am currently using your target pattern method. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

i give you simple example.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Password strength checker in jQuery</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery Library-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/passwordscheck.css" /><!-- Include Your CSS file here-->
<script src="js/passwordscheck.js"></script><!-- Include Your jQUery file here-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h2>Password Strength Checking with jQuery</h2>
<hr>
</div>
<div id="content">
<form id="register">
<label for="password"><b>Password : </b></label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Type Your Password here"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="result"></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#password').keyup(function() {
$('#result').html(checkStrength($('#password').val()))
})
function checkStrength(password) {
var strength = 0
if (password.length < 6) {
$('#result').removeClass()
$('#result').addClass('short')
return 'Too short'
}
if (password.length > 7) strength += 1
// If password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value.
if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1
// If it has numbers and characters, increase strength value.
if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1
// If it has one special character, increase strength value.
if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
// If it has two special characters, increase strength value.
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
// Calculated strength value, we can return messages
// If value is less than 2
if (strength < 2) {
$('#result').removeClass()
$('#result').addClass('weak')
return 'Weak'
} else if (strength == 2) {
$('#result').removeClass()
$('#result').addClass('good')
return 'Good'
} else {
$('#result').removeClass()
$('#result').addClass('strong')
return 'Strong'
}
}
});
```

Reference : [Link](https://www.formget.com/password-strength-checker-in-jquery/)
one of the best example for you 
i hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you for your one and your link too. But I used this method already for comparing two password. I want some exact answers for Icon changing things.  Now I got the ans .Thank you once again